# Passing and retrieving query vars in wordpress

Tags: permalinks, wp-query, url-rewriting

I have two authors pages, one displays about 5 posts.  Then I'm trying to setup another page that will be all of their posts.  I have created a template called moreauthorposts.php and I'm trying to pass the author variable to this page.  Problem is if i pass domain.com/more-author-posts?author=johndoe it gets stripped out.  How can I retrieve this value?  Is this even possible in wordpress?  I know WP Rewrite is jacking my URL structure somehow I'm just not sure.

I've tried:

```
get_query_var('author')
```

and tried reading this but didn't have any luck:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Query_Overview

Suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I'm almost sure that `author` is built-in, so use something like `author_more`. You will need to add that var to `query_vars` first. Example:

```
// add `author_more` to query vars
add_filter( 'init', 'add_author_more_query_var' );
function add_author_more_query_var()
{
    global $wp;
    $wp->add_query_var( 'author_more' );
}
```

Then on your `more-author-posts.php` template call it like this:

```
if ( get_query_var( 'author_more' ) )
{
    // do your stuff
}
```

### Update

This works in the following URl example/use case:

```
http://example.com/index.php?author_more=value
```

But if you want to use this as fancy URl, you need to add a rewrite rule:

```
add_action('init','add_author_more_rewrite_rule');
function add_author_more_rewrite_rule()
{
    add_rewrite_rule(
        'more-author-posts/(\d*)$',
        'index.php?author_more=$matches[1]',
        'top'
    );
}
```

Now you can use it like this

```
http://example.com/more-author-posts/value
```

Comment: Ok so I added the query vars into the functions.php.  Then added the other code to my more author posts.  What would be the correct URL structure to pass these through?  I know that paged uses the format of /page/2 but doing more-author-posts/more_author/johndoe doesnt' seem to be working?

Comment: i updated the answer

Comment: Problem is im not trying to pass the vars to index.php. Im trying to pass them to the custom template I have developed since it looks completely different from index.  So if I pass values to moreauthor.php?author_more=johndoe .. that doesnt seem to work.  Doing something wrong here?

Comment: @בניית אתרים looks like a very clear answer! @codeisforeva You shouldn't be calling the template file directly, should you? index.php is just the root file of wordpress, every rewrite rule should go through there.

Comment: So its not possible to setup a custom template and pass custom vars to it in wordpress?  I would think this would be a massive limitation of the platform.

Comment: Got it to work with index.php, much thanks for the help. Just seems weird you can't do this with other templates.

Comment: not really beacuse you can manage all gets thrugh one file index.php

Comment: @codeisforeva: The `index.php` in the rewrite rule is the `index.php` in the root directory of WordPress, not the `index.php` in your template file. You can still choose which template should be displayed, by hooking into the `template_include` filter.