# How to pass custom parameter to WP_Query for filtering in pre_get_posts

Tags: wp-query, ajax, pre-get-posts

I have an ajax request that returns the result of a WP_Query loop.

I would like to detect in pre_get_posts filter the specific wp_query instance that is used in the ajax handler.

I thought placing a custom parameter in the $args of the WP_Query in the ajax handler:

```
$args= array(...,
            'ajax' => 'AJAX',//custom param for detection of specific WP_Query instance
            ....);
```

and by this way detecting the specific instance in pre_get_post:

```
 if(isset($query->query_vars['ajax']){
    Do stuff
 }
```

I do not know if this has any sense to you...

Thanks¡¡

Comment: If you [mean like this (look for `my_variable`)](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/98748/21376), then yes, that works.

Comment: thanks I meant that, the only issue that worried me after reading your response was : "I do not know if passing additional variables like that is by design, so be aware that that may be unofficial behavior." Can any proble arise in future versions of WP?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can access query variables (including custom ones) via the `WP_Query::get()` method.

For example:

```
$my_query = new WP_Query( array(
      ...
      'wpse105219_custom_var' => 'foobar',
      ...
) );
```

To 'catch' this at `pre_get_posts`:

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpse105219_pre_get_posts', 10 );
function wpse105219_pre_get_posts( $query ){
      if( $query->get( 'wpse105219_custom_var' ) == 'foobar' ){
         //Alter $query
      }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I suppose that this practice is accepted by wp...

Comment: Yes, its fine to use this. If you want the custom variable to be extracted from the url, e.g. `www.mysite.com?wpse105219_custom_var=foobar` then you need to add it via the `query_vars` filter: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/20946/as-soon-as-i-add-a-custom-query-var-using-the-filter-my-pages-point-to-an-archi