# Applying $posts_clauses filter to specific queries only

Tags: posts, filters

I use this code for some kind of sorting but it brakes some theme parts, like "Last articles" in footer, and content part after products.

I understand that $posts_clauses brakes other content, how to filter it?

```
/**
* Sorting out of stock WooCommerce products - Order product collections by stock status, in-stock products first.
*/
class iWC_Orderby_Stock_Status
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        // Check if WooCommerce is active
        if (in_array('woocommerce/woocommerce.php', apply_filters('active_plugins', get_option('active_plugins')))) {
            add_filter('posts_clauses', array($this, 'order_by_stock_status'), 2000);
        }
    }

    public function order_by_stock_status($posts_clauses)
    {
        global $wpdb;

        // only change query on WooCommerce loops
        if( is_woocommerce() && ( is_shop() || is_product_category() || is_product_tag() ) ) {
            $posts_clauses['join']      .= " INNER JOIN $wpdb->postmeta istockstatus ON ($wpdb->posts.ID = istockstatus.post_id) ";
            $posts_clauses['orderby']    = " istockstatus.meta_value ASC, " . $posts_clauses['orderby'];
            $posts_clauses['where']      = " AND istockstatus.meta_key = '_stock_status' AND istockstatus.meta_value <> '' " . $posts_clauses['where'];
        }


        return $posts_clauses;
    }
}
new iWC_Orderby_Stock_Status;
```

Comment: *Untested*, but you could try changing your conditional statement to  `if($query->is_main_query() && is_woocommerce() && ( is_shop() || is_product_category() || is_product_tag() ) ) {`. Note that you should also pass the `$query` parameter to your method, e.g. `public function order_by_stock_status($posts_clauses, $query)`.

Comment: @DaveRomsey Thank you, but unfortunately it breaks my site.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem of needing to only apply $post_clauses to specific loops/queries and was able to use [THIS](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/105219/how-to-pass-custom-parameter-to-wp-query-for-filtering-in-pre-get-posts) solution provided by [Stephen Harris](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/9364/stephen-harris):

> You can access query variables (including custom ones) via the
>   WP_Query::get() method.
>
> For example:
>
> ```
> $my_query = new WP_Query( array(
>       ...
>       'wpse105219_custom_var' => 'foobar',
>       ...
> ) );
> ```
>
> To 'catch' this at pre_get_posts:
>
> ```
> add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpse105219_pre_get_posts', 10 );
> function wpse105219_pre_get_posts( $query ){
>       if( $query->get( 'wpse105219_custom_var' ) == 'foobar' ){
>          //Alter $query
>       }
> }
> ```