# Request parameters in $_GET do not match URL called

Tags: urls

I have a WP plugin which uses the request parameter "type" to determine what code-file to load in order to do some processing. The code which handles this is as follows:

```
add_shortcode ('myplugin_frontend_main', 'MyPlugin_user_dispatcher');

function MyPlugin_user_dispatcher ($args=array())
{
    $type = $_GET['type'];
    $func = $_GET['func'];

    $typefile = ucwords($type). '.php';
    require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . "/$typefile");
    $class  = 'MyPlugin_Controller_' . ucfirst($type);
    $object = new $class();
    echo $object->$func($args);
}
```

The strange thing is this, if I call

```
http://localhost/wordpress/?page_id=4&type=userform&func=edit&noheader=true&ot=product_add&id=14&store=1
```

and add

```
var_dump ($_GET);
exit ();
```

to the code, my var_dump() prints out the following:

```
array
  'page_id' => string '4' (length=1)
  'type' => string 'user' (length=4)
  'func' => string 'main' (length=4)
  'store' => string '1' (length=1)
```

So somehow, $_GET does not contain what I call through the address bar (or by clicking on a link with the same content).

Does anybody have any idea what's going on here?

Greetings/Thanks
R

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WordPress will typically filter off query arguments unless you tell it about those arguments and ask it not to.

From [this older tutorial](http://www.webopius.com/content/137/using-custom-url-parameters-in-wordpress), you can see how to add a new query variable to WordPress (so it won't get stripped out):

```
add_filter('query_vars', 'parameter_queryvars' );
function parameter_queryvars( $qvars )
{
    $qvars[] = 'myvar';
    return $qvars;
}
```

There is an alternative suggestion in the first answer of [this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/8229/passing-and-retrieving-query-vars-in-wordpress):

```
//add author_more to query vars
function add_author_more_query_var() {
    global $wp;
    $wp->add_query_var('author_more');
}

add_filter('init', 'add_author_more_query_var');
```

Once you do that, though, you need to also be aware of some **reserved terms** within WordPress.  There are just some terms you can't use for custom data because they're already used elsewhere.  The full list of reserved terms is [in the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy#Reserved_Terms).

A quick glance shows that "type" is in the reserved list ... which could be why it's changing when you try to use it.

Comment: Thank you so much, I will use your suggestions to fix my code first thing tomorrow morning.

Comment: Please allow me one more clarifying point: this is only for GET parameters, right. I can put anything through post without registering that parameter name, right?

Comment: So far as I know, yes. But you'll still want to avoid anything in the reserved terms list.