# How can i display in themplate file only a few post

Tags: archives, add-theme-support

How guys , i my archive themplate i have 3 tipe of themes:
-poster
-complex
-simple

How can i display a certain number of post for arhive themes:

Ex: for my poster i want to display 24 posts(only the poster and title), for complex i want to display 12 posts(full with excerpt..), for simple i eant to display 30 ( only titles)

I have tree themes for the archive.php

Archive.php

```
<div class="breadcrumbs">
    <?php if(function_exists('bcn_display'))
    {
        bcn_display();
    }?>
</div>

<div class="art-content-film">
<div class="box-lay"> 
                <a href="?afisare=complex" class="grid" title="Grid"><span></span></a>  
                <a href="?afisare=poster" class="poster" title="Poster"><span></span></a> 
                <a href="?afisare=simple" class="list" title="List"><span></span></a> 
</div> 
<?php
$view = 'poster';
$mode = stripslashes( $_GET["afisare"] );
$modes = array('complex', 'simple', 'poster');
if(in_array($mode, $modes)) $view = $mode;
get_template_part('persoane', $view);
?>
</div>

<div class="art-sidebar1"> 
<?php include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/sidebar/actors.php'); ?>
<?php include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/publicitate/ad300.php'); ?>
</div>
```

persoane-poster.php

```
<div class="art-Post">
    <div class="art-Post-tl"></div>
    <div class="art-Post-tr"></div>
    <div class="art-Post-bl"></div>
    <div class="art-Post-br"></div>
    <div class="art-Post-tc"></div>
    <div class="art-Post-bc"></div>
    <div class="art-Post-cl"></div>
    <div class="art-Post-cr"></div>
    <div class="art-Post-cc"></div>
    <div class="art-Post-body">
<?php is_tag(); ?>
<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

<div class="bposter">
<a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php printf(__('Film %s'), the_title_attribute('echo=0')); ?>">
<img src="/scripts/timthumb.php?src=<?php the_field('img_actor'); ?>&h=120&w=90&zc=1" alt="" title="<?php the_title(); ?>" /></a>
<div class="bpt"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php printf(__('Permanent Link to %s', 'kubrick'), the_title_attribute('echo=0')); ?>">
<?php the_title(); ?>
</a></div>
</div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<div class="cleared"></div>

</div>
</div>

<div class="nav">
<?php if(function_exists('wp_paginate')) {wp_paginate();} ?>
</div>
<?php if ($prev_link || $next_link): ?>

<?php endif; ?>

<?php else : ?>
<div class="art-Post">
    <div class="art-Post-tl"></div>
    <div class="art-Post-tr"></div>
    <div class="art-Post-bl"></div>
    <div class="art-Post-br"></div>
    <div class="art-Post-tc"></div>
    <div class="art-Post-bc"></div>
    <div class="art-Post-cl"></div>
    <div class="art-Post-cr"></div>
    <div class="art-Post-cc"></div>
    <div class="art-Post-body">
<div class="art-Post-inner art-article">

<div class="art-PostContent">

<?php
    if ( is_category() ) { // If this is a category archive
        printf("<h2 class='center'>".__("Sorry, but there aren't any posts in the %s category yet.", "kubrick").'</h2>', single_cat_title('',false));
    } else if ( is_date() ) { // If this is a date archive
        echo('<h2>'.__("Sorry, but there aren't any posts with this date.", "kubrick").'</h2>');
    } else if ( is_author() ) { // If this is a category archive
        $userdata = get_userdatabylogin(get_query_var('author_name'));
        printf("<h2 class='center'>".__("Sorry, but there aren't any posts by %s yet.", "kubrick")."</h2>", $userdata->display_name);
    } else {
        echo("<h2 class='center'>".__('No posts found.', 'kubrick').'</h2>');
    }
    if(function_exists('get_search_form')) get_search_form();
?>

</div>
<div class="cleared"></div>


</div>

        <div class="cleared"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Please try to rewrite this question. It is confusing and it is not clear what you are asking.

Comment: do you understand want i want? s_ha_dum ?

Comment: What is "poster", "complex", and "simple"? Are these categories? Custom meta fields? How are you determining which to use?

Comment: no, there are themes, i use 3 themes to display a archive page
persoane-poster.php , persoane-simple.php and persoane-complex.php ... in the admin of my site in setting is set to display 10 post... i want to be able to display for each one a number of post i want...somting like this http://tvpedia.org/lista-seriale/seriale-noi-2012

Comment: You are actually toggling [***Themes***](http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development) somehow? Or do you meant [***Template***](http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development#Template_Files)? Either way, how does WordPress, or your code, know which to display?

Comment: excuse... themplates, please look up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. You are toggling your display according to a `$_GET` parameter that you have added to the URL-- this switch in your `archive.php`

```
$view = 'poster';
$mode = stripslashes( $_GET["afisare"] );
$modes = array('complex', 'simple', 'poster');
if(in_array($mode, $modes)) $view = $mode;
get_template_part('persoane', $view);
```

You can alter how many posts will display but that is much too late to do it.

Untested, but I would try a hook on `pre_get_posts`.

```
function toggle_modes($query) {
  global $_GET;
  if (isset($_GET["afisare"])) {
    $modes = array(
      'complex' => 12, 
      'simple' => 30, 
      'poster' => 24
    );
    if (isset($modes[$_GET["afisare"]])) {
      $query->set('posts_per_page',$modes[$_GET["afisare"]]);
    }
  }
}
add_action('pre_get_posts','toggle_modes');
```

Your URL parameters have to be in every request sent to this page or the pagination will get out of sync.

That is the simplest way to go from where you are to where you want to be. It may well not be the best way. You can think about something like: [Passing and retrieving query vars in wordpress](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/8229/passing-and-retrieving-query-vars-in-wordpress)