# Using query_vars filter

Tags: plugin-development, filters, query

I am trying to link out from the WP admin to view posts in a specific way.
The url structure for this is `example.com/post123/?my-preview=456`

`/post123/` is the regular permalink for a post. The `?my-preview=456` allows a section of that post to retrieve information based off of the my-preview value.

I understand that WP strips `$_GET` parameters from the url, so I tried using `add_filter('query_vars','my_query_vars');` and

```
function my_query_vars($query_vars){
    $query_vars[] = 'my-preview';
    return $query_vars;
}
```

On the actual section where I need to get that value, I tried using:

```
global $wp_query;
var_dump($wp_query->query_vars);
```

Even with a url like the example above, the 'my-preview' pair is nowhere to be found in the $wp_query->query_vars array.

Am I not doing the correct steps to register an additional query_var for use later on? If I am, why does it not stick around?

EDIT:
I have also tried:
`add_action('init', 'add_query_vars');`

with

```
function add_query_vars() {
    global $wp;
    $wp->add_query_var('my-preview');
}
```

and `wp_die(var_dump(get_query_var('my-preview')));` gives `string(0) ""`

Comment: [Passing and retrieving query vars in wordpress](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/8229/passing-and-retrieving-query-vars-in-wordpress)

Comment: Thank you for your comment.
1. I am not seeking to extend pretty permalinks. I just want to use $_GET style parameters.
2. I have tried the methods listed in the accepted answer to no avail. I will update my question with that code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The query vars filter is unnecessary for what you're doing here, as you're not using it in a query. Adding it to the URL as a GET parameter will not make it appear in the array of query vars, as there's no mechanism that converts a GET var to a query var, you've only ensured it won't be removed *if it's added to the query*.

As long as the GET var is unique and not reserved by WordPress, there's nothing that should prevent setting and then accessing a GET var via normal means: `$_GET['my-preview']`.

Comment: According to http://codex.wordpress.org/Query_Overview#More_on_WP-.3Eparse_request.28.29 , `parse_request()` strips the $_GET parameters from the URL. When I visit example.com/post123/?my-preview=123 (I doubt my-prevoew is reserved), wp strips the get params and I eventually land on example.com/post123/

Comment: Also, you said there is no mechanism for converting get params into query bars, but that's exactly what step 4 or parse_request does according to that page.

Comment: If query_vars is not the solution, why does wp strip my get params, and what can I do about it?

Comment: parse_request strips get vars for the purpose of parsing the request, it doesn't redirect to that version of the URL. why it doesn't work for you I can't say, I do this all the time without issue- I've just tested on a clean install and twentytwelve theme, and it works as expected.

Comment: Hm...I'll have to try this out and get back on it.

Comment: You were right! It was this plugin: http://wordpress.org/plugins/404-redirected/ that was causing the get params to be stripped. Weird. Now I remember why I never install plugin more than 6 months old without knowing the developer...