# Is a permastruct possible on pages?

Tags: permalinks, url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

Since a couple of weeks I'm trying to create my own rewritings on pages. I read a lot about rewriting with posts and custom post-types.

BUT: I have pages that I call with variables. How is it possible to bring these variables into a permalink-structure?

Currently, I have:

```
www.mysite.com/pagename/?arg1=value1&arg2=value2
```

but I want to have something like

```
www.mysite.com/pagename/value1/value2
```

I have fount the hook post_link which seems to be used on pages and page_link for pages. But page_link doesn't work in the same way. How can I do, what I want to do?

Please help!

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is possible using the $wp->add_query_var function used together with add_rewrite_rule .
Here you have an example:

[Passing and retrieving query vars in wordpress](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/8229/passing-and-retrieving-query-vars-in-wordpress)

If you want more help here is a cut from one of my old plugins:

```
function createRewriteRules() {
        global $wp_rewrite;


 $new_rules = array(
                '(.?.+?)/(stenskott)$' => 'index.php?pagename='.$wp_rewrite->preg_index(2).'&ort='.
                $wp_rewrite->preg_index(1),
                '(.?.+?)/(bilclas)$' => 'index.php?pagename='.$wp_rewrite->preg_index(2).'&ort='.
                $wp_rewrite->preg_index(1),
                '(.?.+?)/(inbrott-i-bil)$' => 'index.php?pagename='.$wp_rewrite->preg_index(2).'&ort='.
                $wp_rewrite->preg_index(1),
                '(.?.+?)/(om-glas)$' => 'index.php?pagename='.$wp_rewrite->preg_index(2).'&ort='.
                $wp_rewrite->preg_index(1),
                '(.?.+?)/(kontakt)$' => 'index.php?pagename='.$wp_rewrite->preg_index(2).'&ort='.
                $wp_rewrite->preg_index(1)
        );
       // Always add your rules to the top, to make sure your rules have priority
        return $wp_rewrite->rules = $new_rules + $wp_rewrite->rules;

}
add_action('generate_rewrite_rules', 'createRewriteRules');

function query_vars($public_query_vars) {

        $public_query_vars[] = "ort";

        return $public_query_vars;
}
add_filter('query_vars', 'query_vars');

add_action('init', 'add_endpoints');
function add_endpoints()
{
    add_rewrite_endpoint('ort', EP_PAGES);
}
```

Comment: Hi Robin, thanks for your answer. But I afraid that this is not what I'm looking for. I've tried what you have written, but my url is not rewritten from www.mysite.com/pagename/?arg1=value1 (entered into the browser adress line) to www.mysite.com/pagename/value1. Any idea?